# Time Reversal OFDM

Tags: filters, ofdm, equalization

I am trying to understand the Time Reversal OFDM  where ,According to my opinion, the channel is reversed in time domain at receiver side and then equalized.

what I found online is something similar to the below diagram:

[image]

but, What's about if the channel can not be known at the transmitter end? I mean it need to be estimated at the receiver end,  how can we perform the time reversal in that case ? 
Is there any reference documents I can read about that topic, that will be really appreciated.

Comment: never saw that. Can you please, as always, link to the reference you build upon? We'll need a precise description what the "TR filter" block does.

Comment: Interesting technique. http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~jpg/papers/conf/spawc04b.pdf

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry for being late. It's as link in the above comment.

Comment: @DanBoschen Yes, but they are talking about it either in MIMO or SIMO. I need to understand its process with SISO system. Could you please explain how can we do it with SISO system ?